# RewriteRule for Nginx does not forward to subfolder

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

My RewriteRule for Apache `RewriteRule ^asset/(.*)$ includes/libs/minify/g=$1 [L]` which is the subfolder /blog/ is working. I activated Nginx on my Server and changed the Rule to `rewrite ^/asset/(.*)$ /includes/libs/minify/g=$1 last;` which does not forward the URL.

```
SEO Url

domain.com/blog/asset/jquery.js?v=1.00

Real Url

domain.com/blog/includes/libs/minify/g=jquery.js?v=1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you need rewrite in `/blog/asset/` URI path. Nginx always operates with full URI, so you rewrite should be

```
rewrite ^/blog/asset/(.*)$ /blog/includes/libs/minify/g=$1 last;
```

but, probably you don't need `rewrite` at all. This should work:

```
location /blog/asset/ {
    alias /path/to/blog/includes/libs/minify/g=;
}
```

Comment: The path should be the root path right? Somehow not working still. If I check my Log I can see that is taking to root path twice `/var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/main/var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/main/blog/includes/libs/minify/g=jtl3.js`

Comment: Show what you did? Also, is `g=jquery.js` a real file or it should be processed by some script?

Comment: No its not a real file

Comment: Then you should use rewrite